# addEventListener on React.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, addeventlistener

I'm trying to run an addEventListener function on a React app, but most of the times it doesn't run as expected.

Not sure if I need to remake it or if its missing something. If so, can you guys help me with that?

```
const light = document.querySelector('.light');
const grid  = document.querySelector('.grid-container, .navbar, #hex-grid');
  if (light){
      grid.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      light.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
      light.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
    });
  };
```

Comment: You're better off using the `onMouseMove` listener directly on the element, like this: `<Grid onMouseMove={handlerFunction} />`

Comment: the second line may not be returning the item you'd like as well.

Comment: is there a reason you are not keeping it contained in react and breaking out to use vanilla listeners?

Comment: No reason, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I read that I could use querySelectorAll and loop through the array. What do you guys think?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed to querySelector the whole app div ('.App'). Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the line in the code `const grid  = document.querySelector('.grid-container, .navbar, #hex-grid');` is wrong.if you need to access many element in the jquery you have to  querySelectorAll(); function.
execute below code,

```
let grids= document.querySelectorAll("'.grid-container, .navbar, #hex-grid');
```

Then you can use JavaScript map function add event listener by looping through the nodes array in the grid variable.

```
grids.map(grid=>(

  grid.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      light.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
      light.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
    });

));
```

I didnt add the `const light = document.querySelector('.light');` since you mentioned the logic and what you need too do using light class node. I only referring the the bug in your code.